# Postgres create an insert return rule

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I am failing to create a rule which will return the insert's data.

The table is:

```
CREATE TABLE foo(a int, b text);
```

My attempt for the rule is:

```
CREATE RULE return_data AS ON INSERT TO foo DO RETURN *;
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason you want to use a rule for this? You can just use the RETURNING clause to return all values for the row (e.g. `INSERT INTO foo VALUES (1, 'test') RETURNING *;`)

Comment: There is another rule and once there is a rule you can't use the returning clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RETURN` isn't a valid command in a rule definition; you can only use `SELECT`, `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`, and `NOTIFY`.

You can create an `ALSO` rule to return the value of the new row, something like this:

```
> CREATE RULE return_data AS ON INSERT TO FOO DO ALSO SELECT NEW.*;
CREATE RULE

> INSERT INTO foo VALUES (1, 'test');
 a |  b
---+------
 1 | test
(1 row)

INSERT 0 1
```

Note that you can do something identical by just adding the RETURNING clause to the INSERT statement:

```
> INSERT INTO foo VALUES (2, 'test 123') RETURNING *;
 a |    b
---+----------
 2 | test 123
(1 row)


INSERT 0 1
```